# Setup NSXMLParser to parse local XML-file

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I've been searching the last few days to find a way to setup the NSXMLParser. The XML-file I need to parse are the following:

```
<matrix>
    <row>eraser*met</row>
    <row>debone*anat</row>
    <row>ani*jalisco</row>
    <row>madwoman*on</row>
    <row>**joy*itsme</row>
    <row>isao***amad</row>
    <row>mends*mio**</row>
    <row>be*parental</row>
    <row>insipid*hai</row>
    <row>bail*modern</row>
    <row>esse*scored</row>
</matrix>
```

I have implemented the NSXMLParser delegate methods:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
```

But i can't figure out how to actually step through the "matrix" and save the rows in an array.

I hope you can help me.

Best regards 
Sebastian

**EDIT:**

Here is the whole XML-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<grid version="1">
    <matrix>
        <row>eraser*met*</row>
        <row>debone*anat</row>
        <row>ani*jalisco</row>
        <row>madwoman*on</row>
        <row>**joy*itsme</row>
        <row>isao***amad</row>
        <row>mends*mio**</row>
        <row>be*parental</row>
        <row>insipid*hai</row>
        <row>bail*modern</row>
        <row>esse*scored</row>
    </matrix>
    <clues>
        <across>
            <clue>Rubber</clue>
            <clue>Intro to physics?</clue>
            <clue>Fish prep?</clue>
            <clue>Med school subj.</clue>
            <clue>Tropical cuckoo bird</clue>
            <clue>State in W Mexico</clue>
            <clue>Insane female</clue>
            <clue>Not off</clue>
            <clue>Happiness</clue>
            <clue>&quot;Who's there?&quot; response</clue>
            <clue>Golfer Aoki</clue>
            <clue>Diary of ___ Housewife</clue>
            <clue>Fixes</clue>
            <clue>O Sole ___</clue>
            <clue>To exist</clue>
            <clue>Maternal or paternal</clue>
            <clue>Vapid</clue>
            <clue>Yes, in Yokohama</clue>
            <clue>Remove water from a boat</clue>
            <clue>Contemporary</clue>
            <clue>&quot;___ quam videri&quot; (North Carolina's motto)</clue>
            <clue>Tallied</clue>
        </across>
        <down>
            <clue>Dutch cheese</clue>
            <clue>Drink</clue>
            <clue>Actress Sofer</clue>
            <clue>Perceived to be</clue>
            <clue>Ivory Coast's largest city</clue>
            <clue>Lisa, to Bart, briefly</clue>
            <clue>Therefore</clue>
            <clue>Stack of firewood</clue>
            <clue>Take pleasure in</clue>
            <clue>Drain</clue>
            <clue>500 sheets</clue>
            <clue>Lens holders</clue>
            <clue>My ___, Vietnam</clue>
            <clue>Red Bordeaux</clue>
            <clue>Preserve</clue>
            <clue>Perform</clue>
            <clue>Printing widths</clue>
            <clue>Suffocate</clue>
            <clue>Puget Sound city</clue>
            <clue>Swiss river</clue>
            <clue>Did penance</clue>
            <clue>Swedish soprano Jenny</clue>
        </down>
    </clues>
    <hints>
        <across>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
        </across>
        <down>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
            <hints></hints>
        </down>
    </hints>
</grid>
```

I haven't typed in the hints yet, but they will be there before the release.

Comment: you have this data only or more data comes in xml file pls give me the xml whole format i will give a parsing code it is better then nsxml parser.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your quick response. I edited my post so you can see the whole XML-file

Comment: Could you make code to parse the full XML? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track already. The `NSXMLParser` will begin calling these methods when you call the `parse` method on it. Because your question has some sample xml here is a (ruff) sample of how to implement a custom `NSXMLParserDelegate` class. Please note I copied the above xml to a file named "MatrixList.xml" in my project folder.

`MatrixList.h`:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface MatrixList : NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (readonly) NSMutableArray *rows; // property to access results
-(id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url;
@end
```

`MatrixList.m`:

```
#import "MatrixList.h"
@implementation MatrixList{
    NSXMLParser *parser;
    NSMutableString *charactersFound;
}
@synthesize rows = _rows;
-(void)parserDidStartDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
        // These objects are created here so that if a document is not found they will not be created
    _rows = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    charactersFound = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict{
    // clear the characters for new element
    [charactersFound setString:@""];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    // add string found to the mutable string
    [charactersFound appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"row"]){
        // If we are done with a row add the rows contents, a string, to the rows array
        [_rows addObject:[charactersFound copy]];
    }
    [charactersFound setString:@""];
}
-(void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser{
    // This method is handy sometimes
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser parseErrorOccurred:(NSError *)parseError{
    NSLog(@"error:%@",parseError.localizedDescription);
}
-(id)initWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url{
    if ((self = [super init])){
        parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        parser.delegate = self;
        [parser parse]; // This is for an example, You might not want to call parse here, depending on context
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

This class is used like so:

```
// My copy is in the bundle, You could use a url for the docs directory instead
NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MatrixList" withExtension:@"xml"];
MatrixList *matrix = [[MatrixList alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL];
NSLog(@"rows:%@",matrix.rows);
```

With the above code the console will produce:

```
rows:(
    "eraser*met",
    "debone*anat",
    "ani*jalisco",
    "madwoman*on",
    "**joy*itsme",
    "isao***amad",
    "mends*mio**",
    "be*parental",
    "insipid*hai",
    "bail*modern",
    "esse*scored"
)
```

This code is not refined at all, but I think it's a good general example of how to parse some basic xml.

Comment: Thanks a lot NJones :) Do you know what the best and fastest way are to store every single character in an array? :)